# Closed form of $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}a_n+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, generating-functions, partial-fractions

I was given this sequence and I need to find a closed form.
$$a_0=1,a_1=2$$
$$\text{and } \forall n \geq0\text{  }  a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}a_n+1$$
I tried defining the following generating function:
$$A(q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nq^n$$
Then I managed to find that
$$A(q)=\frac{1}{1-q}+\frac{q}{1-q}-\frac{2q^2}{1-q}+\frac{q^2}{(1-q)^2}$$
But I don't know how to take it from here. I'm assuming we need to do some partial fraction decomposition in a certain way but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: Do you know how to expand $1/(1-q)$ out a generating function? What about $q^2 / (1-q)^2$? (As a heads up, $ 1 + q - 2q^2 = (1-q)(1+2q)$, so you could simplify slightly).  $\quad$ Can you show how you derived the $A(q) = 1/(1-q) + \ldots $? I don't think that is correct, because it doesn't yield the sequence $1, 2, 3, 7, 22, \ldots$

Comment: The sequence is [OEIS A007660](https://oeis.org/A007660)

Comment: As Calvin Lin said, your generating function is wrong. The one you got begins with $1+2q+q^2+2q^3+\cdots$ which will give $a_2=1$ and $a_3 = 2$ instead of the correct values $a_2=3$ and $a_3 = 7$.

Comment: @jjagmath how did you manage to find the terms given by my generating function (the wrong one)?

Comment: By dividing $1$ over $1-q$, $q$ over $1-q$, etc.